# Cannot go directly to dynamic route with react-router and webpack-dev-server

Tags: react-router, webpack-dev-server

After starting webpack-dev-server, I can go directly to a static route (e.g. `http://localhost:3456/one`), but I cannot go directly to a dynamic route (e.g. `http://localhost:3456/two/1234`).

I believe I am missing something in my webpack-dev-server config, but not sure what.

The browser console outputs this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3456/two/dev-bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3456/two/dev-bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  entry: [
    "./index.js",
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "dev-bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "dev.html")
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3456,
    stats: "minimal"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import ComponentOne from "./components/ComponentOne"
import ComponentTwo from "./components/ComponentTwo"

const MyApp = () => (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentOne} />
        <Route exact path="/one" component={ComponentOne} />
        <Route path="/two/:id" component={ComponentTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
)

export default hot(module)(MyApp)
```

ComponentTwo.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

export default class ComponentTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ComponentTwo for {this.props.match.params.id}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to resolve this by updating part of the webpack config:

```
output: {
  filename: "dev-bundle.js",
  publicPath: "/",    // added this line
},
```

The console error remains, but at least the page loads.

Comment: I havent console error with your solution(webpack 4) and dinamic routes cheking manually works well.Upvote you.