# React-Router Link to= attempts to download x.app.js on click

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can someone explain why this terribly simple router setup:

```
        <Router>
            <Switch>                
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                { this.props.loggedIn() &&
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path='/projects' component={Tools} />
                        <Route path='/project/:project_id' component={EditProject} />
                        <Route exact path='/calculator' component={Calculator} />
                    </div>
                }                
                <Route exact component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

And a simple page link:

```
<Link to={`/project/${proj.ID}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" /></Link>
```

Results in (*when clicking on the link*):

[image]

Why is it attempting to download a JS file? I've checked and double-checked the code, and as far as I can see, it's correct. Anyone spot anything stupid?

**EDIT**

Before anyone thinks that project_id is infact x.app.js here is the raw object I'm using:

```
{
    Coords: "2389572935"
    CustomerID: 0
    FacilityType: 0
    ID: 4
    Name: "Loki Testing New Project"
    UserID: 2
    VerifiedByBL: 0
    VerifiedByCustomer: 0
}
```

Comment: put `exact` prop.  `<Route path='/project/:project_id' exact component={EditProject} />`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your HTML page where you initialise the app? How are you calling your "app.js" into the page?

Comment: You shouldn't use exact when you're expecting params, as far as I know. @MehmetSeckin - I'm running under webpack dev server, I've not had to include my bundle as yet.

Comment: @LokiSinclair [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690137/cannot-go-directly-to-dynamic-route-with-react-router-and-webpack-dev-server/50705583#50705583) looks like a similar issue, can you try the suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705583/824495)?

Comment: Could you post more code just before you call or render the Link? Maybe you are not using the same object, or maybe something weird is happening in between. Try `to={'/project/' + proj.ID}` and also try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(proj.ID))` to see what you get. Also try a hardcoded test `to={'/project/4'}` or whatever your id is, just to see that the router is working fine..